# How to fix export 'NotificationKind' was not found in 'rxjs' error

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, ngrx

NotificationKind has been deprecated [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/deprecations) but when building an angular 8 app it throws the following error:

```
ng build

Date: 2019-06-08T16:44:40.118Z
Hash: 7f30f6f31d45ce95291b
Time: 12019ms
chunk {main} main-es5.js, main-es5.js.map (main) 72.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills) 662 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es5.js, runtime-es5.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es5.js, styles-es5.js.map (styles) 1.45 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor-es5.js, vendor-es5.js.map (vendor) 3.93 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in /var/app/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/fesm5/effects.js 401:33-49
"export 'NotificationKind' was not found in 'rxjs'
ERROR in /var/app/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/fesm5/effects.js 403:56-72
"export 'NotificationKind' was not found in 'rxjs'
ERROR in /var/app/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/fesm5/effects.js 404:33-49
"export 'NotificationKind' was not found in 'rxjs'
ERROR in /var/app/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/fesm5/effects.js 407:55-71
"export 'NotificationKind' was not found in 'rxjs'
```

```
{
  "name": "@spotacard/app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "nx lint && ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "affected:apps": "nx affected:apps",
    "affected:libs": "nx affected:libs",
    "affected:build": "nx affected:build",
    "affected:e2e": "nx affected:e2e",
    "affected:test": "nx affected:test",
    "affected:lint": "nx affected:lint",
    "affected:dep-graph": "nx affected:dep-graph",
    "affected": "nx affected",
    "format": "nx format:write",
    "format:write": "nx format:write",
    "format:check": "nx format:check",
    "update": "ng update @nrwl/workspace",
    "update:check": "ng update",
    "workspace-schematic": "nx workspace-schematic",
    "dep-graph": "nx dep-graph",
    "help": "nx help"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.0.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "^8.0.1",
    "@nrwl/nx": "^7.8.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootswatch": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-preset-angular": "7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.0",
    "codelyzer": "~5.0.1",
    "cypress": "3.1.0",
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.6",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "8.0.1",
    "@nrwl/jest": "8.0.1",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.9",
    "ts-jest": "24.0.0",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "8.0.1",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5",
    "prettier": "1.16.4",
    "@angular/cli": "8.0.0"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried upgrading RxJS?

V8 has the minimum version requirements:

- Angular version 8.x
- Angular CLI version 8.0.2
- TypeScript version 3.4.x
- RxJS version 6.5.x

https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v8

**Update 2019-06-10:**

NgRx v8.0.1 has a dep to RxJS 6.4 instead of 6.5

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue. I was able to solve it by running:

`npm install rxjs@6.5.0`